# Angular Material center layout

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

im getting my feet wet with Angular Material.

I have referred to the documentation on angular material website and i am trying to accomplish the foll:
[image: AngularJS Material Toolbar]

the second

tag, that is, the 'name of the master' shld appear in the middle. whereas the position of ngmasters is all right.

this is how im trying to implement this functionality to no avail:

```
<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <p><strong>ngMasters</strong></p>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
            <p>Name of the Master</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</md-toolbar>
```

any help or direction wld be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to apply the [`flex`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children) attribute to the `<div>` so it takes up available space within the `<md-toolbar>`:

```
<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <p><strong>ngMasters</strong></p>
        <div flex="" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
            <p>Name of the Master</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: aah... got it.. i understand it better now. thank you v much.